# Flash - Rotate pictures in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, rotation

I'm learning to use Flash. I'm a newbie.

I need to know how I can create something like this:

http://www.instanttower.ch/gerust-konfigurator.php

Or at least how to rotate an image with the mouse as seen here:

http://www.instanttower.ch/konfigurator/VXSP300SP4.swf

I want to learn to do, so if anyone can guide me appreciate it.

Comment: adjust rotationY property on movieclip you want to rotate

Comment: I think this is more complicated than just using rotationY. The rotated object isn't just a flat image it is a 3d model. This is kind of an advanced subject, but if you really want to learn how to do it, I would recommend a book called Adobe Flash 11 Stage3d (Molehill) Game Development.

Comment: This looks like it's being faked rather then being true 3d. The rotation isn't smooth and always snaps to roughly 25-30 'positions'. So to recreate that, take 25-30 renders and get flash to scrolls through them based on dragging the mouse. Also there is pixelation in the pictures in the second link, adding to the fact that it is just showing images.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved with sequence images, simple timeline control really a few buttons, and basically a switch to allow reverse playing on the timeline(playhead).

I had made the same thing basically a while ago, goTo the link and you can download my file and add your images..complete with source code.its free

http://ffiles.com/flash/3_dimensional/t_shirt_3d_display_with_rotation_3131.html

hope it helps..